On the parity of the sum $\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid aj^2+bjk+ck^2}(aj^2+bjk+ck^2)$
QUESTION. Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$. How to determine the parity of the sum
$$S_p(a,b,c)=\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid aj^2+bjk+ck^2}(aj^2+bjk+ck^2)$$
in terms of $a,b,c$ and $p$? Can one find an explicit pattern for the parity of $S_p(a,b,c)$?
Your comments are welcome!

If $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ does not factor over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then the count is just $0$. If it does factor, say $ax^2+bxy+cy^2 = (q x+ r y)(s x+t y)$, then the answer is $N_p(-q/r)+N_p(-s/t)$, of course excluding certain degenerate cases which are easy to deal with separately, where I'm writing $N_p(z)$ for the number of elements $x$ of $\mathcal{S}_p={1,2,\ldots,p-1}$ such that the minimal representative in $\mathcal{S}_p$ of $zx$ is greater than $x$. So I think your question boils down to understanding this function $N_p$.

To see that this is not a reduction to a harder problem: if $p|a$, we can ignore the first term and we are really counting the zeros (over $\mathbb{F}_p$) of $y(bx+cy)$ satisfying $x,y \neq 0$ and $x<y$. If we further assume $p \nmid b,c$, then this number equals $N_p(-b/c)$, in the notation of my previous comment. So if I know your function $S_p$, I also know my function $N_p$.

Note that the summand $aj^2+bjk+ck^2$ cannot be replaced by its nonnegative residue modulo $p$.

Yes, I completely misread the question. I beg your pardon.

Surely it's simpler to first handle the sum without the condition that $p\nmid aj^2+bjk + ck^2$, which should have a closed-form formula, and then subtract off the sum with the condition $p\mid aj^2+bjk + ck^2$?

This is not a complete answer.
Claim 1. Let $D=b^2-4ac$. If  $\left( \frac{D}{p}\right)=-1$, then $$S_p(a,b,c)\equiv a\frac{(p-1)^2}{4}+b\frac{(p-1)(p-3)}{8}\pmod{2}.$$
Proof.
Let $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$. Then
\begin{align}
S_p(a,b,c)&\equiv\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\nmid j, 2\nmid k}f(j,k)+\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\nmid j, 2\mid k}f(j,k)+\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\mid j, 2\nmid k}f(j,k)\\
&\equiv \sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\nmid j, 2\nmid k}(a+b+c)+\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\nmid j, 2\mid k}a+\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\mid j, 2\nmid k}c\pmod{2}.
\end{align}
Noting that $\left( \frac{D}{p}\right)=-1$, it follows that
$$4af(j,k)=(2aj+bk)^2-Dk^2\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$$
So $$f(j,k)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\nmid j, 2\nmid k}1 =\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop 2\nmid j, 2\nmid k}1= \frac{p^2-4p+3}{8},$$
$$\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\nmid j, 2\mid k}1 =\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop 2\nmid j, 2\mid k}1= \frac{p^2-1}{8},$$
$$\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop p\nmid f(j,k),2\mid j, 2\nmid k}1 =\sum_{1\le j<k\le p-1\atop 2\mid j, 2\nmid k}1= \frac{p^2-4p+3}{8}$$
and
\begin{align}
S_p(a,b,c)&\equiv(a+b+2c)\frac{p^2-4p+3}{8}+a\frac{p^2-1}{8}\\
&\equiv a\frac{(p-1)^2}{4}+b\frac{(p-1)(p-3)}{8} \pmod{2}.
\end{align}
Remark 1.
Calculations show that if $2\nmid a$, $2\nmid b$, $2 \mid c$ and $\left( \frac{D}{p}\right)=1$, then for almost all odd  prime $p$, $S_p(a,b,c)\equiv a\frac{(p-1)^2}{4}+b\frac{(p-1)(p-3)}{8}\pmod{2}.$
For example,  when $(a,b,c)=(123,567,456)$,$\left( \frac{D}{p}\right)=1$ and $p\leq 1987$, $$S_p(123,567,456)\equiv 123\frac{(p-1)^2}{4}+567\frac{(p-1)(p-3)}{8}\pmod{2}$$
except for $p=19.$

Conj. If $2\nmid a$, $2\nmid b$, $2 \mid c$, $\left( \frac{D}{p}\right)=1$ and $\left( \frac{ac(a+b+c)}{p}\right)\neq 0$, then $$S_p(a,b,c)\equiv a\frac{(p-1)^2}{4}+b\frac{(p-1)(p-3)}{8}\equiv\frac{p^2-1}{8}\pmod{2}.$$

Something must be wrong in your argument: unless I am mistaken $S_{11}(1,1,1)=4785$ while $(1+1+1)(11^2-4.11+3)/8=30$, and $(-3,11)=-1$.

@Henri Cohen I missed two cases:$2\nmid j, 2\mid k$ and $2\mid j, 2\nmid k$; the proof has been revised. Thank you for your counterexample.

$S_{11}(1,2,2)=8745$,  $(1+2+4)(11^2-4.11+3)/8+2.(11^2-1)/8=100$, and $(-4/11)=-1$.

@ Henri Cohen Typo: the last term should be $a\frac{p^2-1}{8}.$ Thank you for your counterexample.

If $p$ never divides $f(j,k)$, then the sum can be evaluated directly, i.e. there is no need to split it into the cases. For example, Maple computes the sum right away: $$\sum_{1\leq j<k\leq p-1} aj^2+bjk+ck^2 = \frac{(p-2)(p-1)p (2 a p +3 b p +6 c p -2 a -b -2 c)}{24}.$$
